# is it ok to gitlab-backup restore after ssh broken pipe?

Tags: ssh, backup, connection, gitlab

I am trying to migrate gitlab-ce. Since my backup file is almost up to 200G it takes very long time to restore.

I executed `gitlab-backup restore` and after some hours got `ssh:broken pipe`.

As far as I know, a task will be terminated when ssh connection disconnected. However when I connect to server again I still list my gitlab-backup process.

Should I re-run `gitlab-backup restore`? or is it OK to keep process?

```
# After I got broken pipe, I still list my task with ps
$ ps -ef | grep backup
root      1122   654  0 01:49 pts/2    00:00:00 bash /opt/gitlab/bin/gitlab-backup restore BACKUP=1696610936_2023_10_07_13.12.3
git       1123  1122  2 01:49 pts/2    00:05:50 /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/rake gitlab:backup:restore BACKUP=1696610936_2023_10_07_13.12.3
root     16057 13826  0 05:27 pts/3    00:00:00 grep --color=auto backup
```

Comment: Just a tip for the future: Use _screen_ or _tmux_ if you anticipate connection interruptions and/or the process taking a long time.

Comment: @DanielB Thanks for the tip. next time i will try `tmux`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like "gitlab-backup" does not work after ssh session close. It is not a problem of gitlab but misusage of ssh connection.

So I changed my ssh connect command to access gitlab-server

```bash
# previous
$ ssh account@ip
# modified - send null packet every 120 sec
$ ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=120 account@ip
```